# Why does Ubuntu spends so much time setting the network at startup?

Tags: networking, startup, resolv.conf, dnsmasq

Booting got very slow about the time I began testing Ubuntu 12.10 quantal. I think networking is one of the causes. I suspect networking is doing a lot of work that is unnecessary (since it was very fast in 12.04). What might I do?

```
Apr 16 08:05:40 retrograde NetworkManager[1291]: <info> (eth1): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Apr 16 08:05:40 retrograde NetworkManager[1291]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 16 08:05:40 retrograde NetworkManager[1291]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 16 08:05:40 retrograde NetworkManager[1291]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Apr 16 08:07:14 retrograde dnsmasq[1446]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 16 08:07:14 retrograde dnsmasq[1446]: using nameserver 127.0.1.1#53
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your nameserver does not resolve IP addresses. It takes then several seconds, before taking a default value.

Try to define a working DNS server at /etc/networking/interfaces or via GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You are running two instances of dnsmasq.  First, you are running the NetworkManager-controlled instance of dnsmasq which listens at 127.0.1.1; second you are running a server instance of dnsmasq which listens on all interfaces and forwards queries to 127.0.1.1.

The NetworkManager-controlled instance isn't necessary. Disable it by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and commenting out the line `dns=dnsmasq`. Then `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Do you have a reason for running the dnsmasq server instance? If not then remove it: `apt-get remove dnsmasq`.

This will at least simplify things so you can debug more easily.